# A value of type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to a variable of type '_BlocProviderInherited<T>'

Tags: flutter, bloc

So, my code:

```
Type _typeOf<T>() => T;

abstract class BlocBase {
  void dispose();
}

class BlocProvider<T extends BlocBase> extends StatefulWidget {
  BlocProvider({
    Key? key,
    required this.child,
    required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final Widget child;
  final T bloc;

  @override
  _BlocProviderState<T> createState() => _BlocProviderState<T>();

  static T of<T extends BlocBase>(BuildContext context) {
    final type = _typeOf<_BlocProviderInherited<T>>();
    _BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =
        context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<type>()?.widget;
    return provider?.bloc;
  }
}

class _BlocProviderState<T extends BlocBase> extends State<BlocProvider<T>> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    widget.bloc.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new _BlocProviderInherited<T>(
      bloc: widget.bloc,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class _BlocProviderInherited<T> extends InheritedWidget {
  _BlocProviderInherited({
    Key? key,
    required Widget child,
    required this.bloc,
  }) : super(key: key, child: child);

  final T bloc;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_BlocProviderInherited oldWidget) => false;
}
```

The offending line is this one:

```
_BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =
        context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<type>()?.widget;
```

And throws the error:

```
A value of type 'Widget?' can't be assigned to a variable of type '_BlocProviderInherited<T>'.
```

Edit: Additionally, it is throwing an error on the next line:

```
return provider?.bloc;
```

Error:

```
A value of type 'T?' can't be returned from the method 'of' because it has a return type of 'T'.
```

This is previously working code from my published app that no longer works after upgrading flutter from a quite old version.

Anyone know what it wants from me?

Edit: Have included full code, as referenced functions were not previously shown.

Comment: Is this code you wrote or code from the Bloc package you are using?

Comment: Code I wrote. There is no package, my only import is: 'package:flutter/material.dart';

Comment: The implementation is wrong the answer to your question will not help you with this code working. I would suggest you use a Bloc library or at least look at how it is implemented under the hood. Regarding your question - you try to assign `Widget widget` to `_BlocProviderInherited<T> provider`, which obviously won't work, and that is basic programming and basic flutter, so I would suggest you to read the documentation about that also.

Answer (score 1):

```dart
_BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =
        context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<type>()?.widget;
```

This line fails because the variable types don't match. A `Widget?` is not a `_BlocProviderInherited<T>`. My guess is that the `extends InheritedWidget` used to mean that `_BlocProviderInherited<T>` had a type of `Widget`, but now (based on the InheritedWidget [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) and the method [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BuildContext/getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType.html)) that is not the case.

`A value of type 'T?' can't be returned from the method 'of' because it has a return type of 'T'.`
This error is caused by trying to return a variable that can be null from a method that only returns non-null variables. Flutter has changed a lot between major releases, including adding null safety. To fix it, change that line to `return provider!.bloc;` or provide a default bloc after: `return provider?.bloc ?? <default value here>`. Either way the returned value won't be null.

Comment: @bisclavret Please accept the answer if it solved your problem/helped. If not, can you please tell me what didn't work/help?

Comment: Hi mate, sorry I have been away and just looking at this now.   So you solved part 2, in that I can just remove the '?' and it works fine now.   The problem with the first part is you have given me some information, but I don't know what actual code to use to make this work again.

Comment: @Bisclavret based on the documentation, it looks like you'll have to redo `_BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =       context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<type>()?.widget;` to be `_BlocProviderInherited<T extends InheritedWidget> provider = context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType<type>()?.widget` and change `<T>` to `<T extends InheritedWidget>` in every place that refers to `_BlocProviderInherited<T>`.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me again, but you can't do what you suggested here.  I changed everything like you said, but it still will not allow _BlocProviderInherited<T extends InheritedWidget> anywhere.   The closest I have come to resolving this is:  _BlocProviderInherited<T> provider =
        context.getElementForInheritedWidgetOfExactType as _BlocProviderInherited<T>;  This results in a compilable app finally, but the logic is wrong and it crashes.